# Transform makes sizes different

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

I have a function which rotates a box, which works fine. When the user is done rotating I want to fit the parent view to the rotated box, but it simply goes all out of proportions and I can't figure out why, as I just exchange the dimensions and properties between rotated view and the parent view.

Rotation:

```
func rotateThisView(gesture : UIRotationGestureRecognizer){
    if activated {
        if gesture.state == .Began || gesture.state == .Changed {
            wrapView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(wrapView.transform, gesture.rotation)
            gesture.rotation = 0
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine as stated, but then when the user is done editing (rotating) I run this function:

```
    wrapPoints = wrapView.center
    wrapDimensions = wrapView.frame
    wrapRotation = wrapView.transform

    print(wrapPoints, wrapDimensions, wrapRotation)
    wrapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: wrapDimensions.width, height: wrapDimensions.height)
    wrapView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    wrapView.center = center

    frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: wrapDimensions.width, height: wrapDimensions.height)
    center = wrapPoints
    transform = wrapRotation
```

And this is where everything gets out of proportions. I've included two screenshots to show whats going. The parent view becomes larger, the rotated views become abnormally large.

[image]
[image]

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: do you really want to change it's frame with it's superview?

Comment: Yeah it's an custom UIView class

Answer (score 1):

You should change the place of `wrapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: wrapDimensions.width, height: wrapDimensions.height)` with `wrapView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`'s place

```
            wrapView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            wrapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: wrapDimensions.width, height: wrapDimensions.height)
            wrapView.center = center
```

Comment: Makes no difference unfortunately

Comment: can you supply a sample project? we need more message to help you

Comment: I can't unfortunately. I solved it though by making another view around the rotated view and setting sites to that. It looks rather clunky,  but it works. I would still like to see how it will be solved in a single view though